# Using instruments to find overflow of the stack in code

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management, instruments

As Documents say, allocations give a heap analysis of the memory.

However, what I feel is my app is crashing because of storing a lot of data on stack, which might be overflowing.

How do I analyze that? Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: Check with memory monitor. For more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518918/instruments-with-ios-why-does-memory-monitor-disagree-with-allocations

Answer (score 1):

First Build your app for Profiling (Command +I); Run it. Select the Allocations tool, Play around with (Use) the application.

In the Allocations you will find a section of **Live Bytes** this is the **current RAM utilization** by your application (*data on stack* I suppose it's the RAM you are talking abt in your question).

**Releasing Objects** that are not currently in use will reduce **Live bytes**

**Overall Bytes** - All bytes (Created & Destroyed + currently live bytes).

[For Further reference refer Instruments Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH40-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Creating and comparing "heapshots" is a good way to start narrowing down the code parts that show no obvious memory management errors at first glance. See my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601958/1126955) for some further reading or check out [this great article](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/590-actually-finding-a-memory-management-error-with-instruments/) directly.